# xml attributes name error?

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

im trying to parse a simple xml string which contain basic attributes

```
<hash>
<engine-type>
I4 DI
</engine-type>
<body-style>
SAV 4D
</body-style>
<year>
2012
</year>
</hash>
```

the problem happened when i tried to print out those 2 attributes engine-type and body-style the xdebug gives error

```
$result = simplexml_load_string($query);
$enginetype = $result->engine-type;
$bodystyle = $result->body-style ;
echo $enginetype .'<br />'. $bodystyle ;
```

those are the errors came from xdebug

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant type - assumed 'type'
Notice: Use of undefined constant style - assumed 'style
```

when i tried to save them to my database the value 0
other attributes just work fine

Comment: http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic - Example #3

Comment: Note, these are not attributes in the XML sense. They are child elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [curly complex syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) to represent identifiers with special characters.

```
$enginetype = $result->{'engine-type'};
$bodystyle = $result->{'body-style'} ;
```

Answer (score 2):

`engine-type` is not a valid label name in PHP, so cannot be used directly to refer to a property of an object.

PHP allows "variable properties", using the curly-brace syntax, which accept a property name as the result of some expression: that expression can be as simple as a string.

```
$result->{'engine-type'};
```

This allows one to construct property names dynamically (which is not needed in this case) like

```
$var = 'bar';
$result->{'foo-'.$var};
```

We have an example of this syntax, dealing with exactly the same sort of scenario as in the question, currently available as **Example #3** on the [SimpleXML Basic Usage](http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic) manual page.

> **Example #3 Getting `<line>`**
>
> ```
> <?php
> include 'example.php';
>
> $movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
>
> echo $movies->movie->{'great-lines'}->line;
> ?>
> ```
>
> The above example will output:
>
> > PHP solves all my web problems

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your expression is being interpreted as variable `$result->engine` minus constant `type`.
Try this insted:

`var_dump($result->{'engine-type'});`